# How to take the inverse laplace transform of this expression

Tags: laplace-transform

$T_3(t)$ is known, and it is possible to calculate an arbitrary $n$th order derivative of $T_3(t)$.

$n_1$, $d_1$, and $d_2$ are constants, and $S_3(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $T_3(t)$.

Is there a way to find the inverse Laplace transform of the following expression in terms of $T_3(t)$ and its derivatives?

$$\frac{n_1S_3(s)}{s^2+d_1s+d_2}$$

If it is possible, how does one go about finding it?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is use convolutions.  (Note that I modified your question slightly because calling both the function and its Laplace transform by the same name is a bad habit and potentially dangerous, and technically wrong.  Just changing the input variable name is not enough.)

The convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$ is:
$$ (f \ast g)(t) = \int_0^t f(t - \tau) g(\tau) \, d\tau$$

It is a known fact that the Laplace transform of a convolution is equal to the product of the Laplace transforms.  In other words,
$$\mathcal L\{f \ast g\} = \mathcal L\{f\} \cdot \mathcal L\{g\}.$$

Let $f \ast g$ denote the convolution of $f$ and $g$, let $\mathcal L$ denote the Laplace transform operator, and let $F$ and $G$ denote the Laplace transforms of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Then since $\mathcal L\{f \ast g\} = F(s)G(s),$ we therefore have $$\mathcal L^{-1}\{F(s)G(s)\} = (f \ast g)(t) = \left(\mathcal L^{-1}\{F\} \ast \mathcal L^{-1}\{G\}\right)(t).$$

In this case:
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{n_1 S_3(s)}{s^2 + d_1s + d_2}\right\}
    &= \mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{n_1}{s^2 + d_1s + d_2} \cdot S_3(s)\right\}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \left(\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{n_1}{s^2 + d_1s + d_2}\right\} \ast \mathcal L^{-1}\left\{S_3\right\} \right)(t)
\end{align*}
We already know that $\mathcal L^{-1}\{S_3\} = T_3(t)$.  Now we just need to find $\mathcal L^{-1} \left\{\dfrac{n_1}{s^2 + d_1s + d_2}\right\}$.  Start by completing the square:
$$
  \frac{n_1}{s^2 + d_1s + d_2} = \frac{n_1}{\left(s + \frac{d_1}2\right)^2 + d_2 - \frac{d_1^2}4}
$$
From here I think it depends on the sign of $d_2 - \dfrac{d_1^2}4$.  You can do some more algebraic manipulations and then use a Laplace transform table.  I didn't take it all the way but it looks like you'll get something involving exponentials and sine, or exponentials and hyperbolic sine - again, depending on the sign of $d_2 - \dfrac{d_1^2}4$.